# Anything not showing in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom class named myCustomCell and it inherits UITableViewCell. I declared the two variables in the class. It gave me crashing when the tableview is called. so, I added "guard" in tableview(_:cellForRowAT). I don't see any error but I don't see anything in cell. Would anyone help me with it?

```
import UIKit

class tableviewtest: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell:myCustomCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? myCustomCell else {
 return   UITableViewCell()

    }
    if searching {
        cell.myLableCell1?.text = searchArr[indexPath.row]

        targetStringItem = searchArr[indexPath.item]

        if let indexForSelectedEng = eng.firstIndex(of: targetStringItem) {
             showTheIndex = indexForSelectedEng

            cell.myLableCell2?.text = String(showTheIndex)
        }

    }
    else {

        cell.myLableCell1?.text = copiedArray[indexPath.row]

        targetStringItem = copiedArray[indexPath.item]
        if let indexForSelectedEng = eng.firstIndex(of: targetStringItem) {
             showTheIndex = indexForSelectedEng
            cell.myLableCell2?.text = String(showTheIndex)
        }
    }

    return cell

}


class myCustomCell:UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLableCell1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myLableCell2: UILabel!

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a classic design mistake and reveals the (practical) uselessness of the conditional downcast.

The class of the custom cell in Interface Builder must be set to `myCustomCell` and the Identifier of the cell must be set to the proper value, too. Then you can remove the `guard` expression.

And please name classes and structs with starting uppercase letter.

---

Side note:

There is a lot of redundant code, the method can be reduced to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myCustomCell

    targetStringItem = searching ? searchArr[indexPath.row] : copiedArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.myLableCell1?.text = targetStringItem
    if let indexForSelectedEng = eng.firstIndex(of: targetStringItem) {
        showTheIndex = indexForSelectedEng
        cell.myLableCell2?.text = String(showTheIndex)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr,vadian. I set the custom class of the TableViewCell in the identity inspector of the interface Builder as myCustomCell And, in the attributes inspector, I set the identifier as cellIdentifier which is in the code on the top of my question. and it gives me this error: "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x116721aa0) to 'zzzzzz.myCustomCell'"

Comment: Please double check the Identity Inspector. The Checkbox "Inherit Module from Target" must be checked and the Target Membership in the File Inspector of the cell must be checked, too.

Comment: Thank you once again, I doubled check and it works perfectly now. your code is much simple and works very well.